# Display In App Price BEFORE User Selects To Purchase Button

Tags: ios, skproduct

I have an app with an in app purchase.  All works as designed... in app purchase works, but I am trying to display the local price **BEFORE** the user selects the Buy Now Button.

Currently, somehow my code will only display the price once the process is initiated...

Here is code

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

NSLog(@"IAP: Received Response");

// add wait text here
iAPnote.text = @"Connecting With App Store...";

SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
int count = [response.products count];

if (count>0) {

    NSLog(@"IAP: Available, starting transaction");

    validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];

    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:validProduct];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

    // shows the cost of the in-app-purchase in the local currency (Canada / United States etc) using SKProduct+LocalizedPrice .h and .m helper files

    [self.iAPprice setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"Price: %@",validProduct.localizedPrice]];


} else {

    NSLog(@"IAP: Item not found");

    UIAlertView *tmp = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"Internet Connection Required"
                        message:@"You must connect to a Wi-Fi  or cellular data network to perform an In-App Purchase."
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [tmp show];
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

You'll notice in the first screenshot that the price is NOT shown... This is the initial view... Once the user taps the Unlock Button, then the action is initiated to look for the price and then display it... How can I make this action happen without the user starting the process... How can I display the price BEFORE the user taps that button?

Is there something in viewDidLoad I need to initiate?

Comment: You should initiate your product request well in advance of the purchase request; typically in `viewDidLoad` or even in `didFinishLaunching` then you can get the price from the `SKProduct`

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks, that did the trick (adding a few lines of code to viewDidLoad)...